# Vue @click counter and update background for 2 minutes for reusable component

Tags: vue.js, onclick, components, counter, setinterval

I have a reusable vue component which is basically a user card that displays an array of data for multiple users.
What I would like to do is when **clicking on the word alert in the corner for a particular user, the background for that users card will change colours for 2 minutes and then revert to the way it was before but it will add the number 1 next to alert** and keep incrementing for each click.

So far I have:

```
<div class="card"  v-for="(item, index) in arrays" :key="item.id" v-bind:id="item.name">
<div class="l"  v-on:click="greet()" >Alert{{count}}</div>
```

which is where I click on alert and display counter.

```
 data () {
    return {
      count: null,
      arrays: [
      {
         name: 'John',
      },
      {
        name: 'Alice',
       }
      ]

...
```

And a function to change colour and counter:

```
greet: function (event) {
     
   var name = this.arrays[1]['name'];
     
     
   var orig = document.getElementById(name).style.background;
   document.getElementById(name).style.background = '#454647';
   setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById(name).style.background = orig; 
   }, 3000);
   
      this.count = this.count + 1;  
      
      
      // setInterval(function(){(document.getElementById(name).style.background = 'blue')}, 3000);
    
    },
```

I have 2 problems, 1. The counter updates and displays for all cards and not only on the one I'm clicking. 2. In order to target the card I'm clicking on to change background I added arrays[1] to test it working on that user but I need a way for it to change according to the user card I clicked on.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need individual counters per card/person like:

```
data () {
    return {
      arrays: [
      {
         name: 'John',
         count:0
      },
      {
        name: 'Alice',
        count:0
       }
      ]
     ...
```

Then you can pass the index of the array to your function like:

```
<div class="card"  v-for="(item, index) in arrays" :key="item.id" v-bind:id="item.name">
  <div class="l"  v-on:click="greet(index)" >Alert{{arrays[index].count}}</div>
</div>
```

then

```
greet: function (arrIndex) {
     
   //var name = this.arrays[1]['name'];
     
     
   var orig = document.getElementById(this.arrays[arrIndex].name).style.background;
   setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById(this.arrays[arrIndex].name).style.background = orig; 
   }, 3000);
     
      this.arrays[arrIndex].count++
      //this.count = this.count + 1; 

      // setInterval(function(){(document.getElementById(name).style.background = 'blue')}, 3000);
    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the colour changed correctly! The counter is still displaying the same number for all cards though, any way to show how many times alert has been clicked for each individual card?

Comment: do you need separate counters per card?

Comment: Yes I need each card to display how many times alert was clicked for their card

Comment: @YJay ive edited my code to do the counters as well, try that.

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting an error message that says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined" when I try clicking on it.

Comment: so i assume it is showing 2 cards, and any of the button throws that error?

Comment: So I actually have 3 cards displaying, it shows the message also for 1 and 0. Seems that for whichever card I click it shows the error message with that number of that card and yes seems they all are displaying same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217115/discussion-between-user9879287-and-yjay).